# trying to show an identity regarding vectors and triangles

Tags: geometry

We have the following situation: $M$ and $N$ are the centroid of the triangles (The point where the medians intersect) Can I show that $\vec{AD} + \vec{BE} + \vec{CF} = 3 \vec{MN} $? Maybe using a barycentric argument would work? MY idea is just to use vector addition. 
[image]

Comment: Do you mean $\vec {DE}$ or $\vec {BE}$?

Comment: yes, let me fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a fixed point, then since $M$ and $N$ are centroids of triangles $ABC$ and $DEF$ respectively

$$\vec{XM} = \frac 13(\vec{XA}+ \vec{XB}+\vec{XC}),$$
$$\vec{XN} = \frac 13(\vec{XD}+ \vec{XE}+\vec{XF}).$$

Subtract last two relations to get an answer.

Comment: I dont understand your solution. Can you explain a little bit more? thank you!

Comment: Recall the definition of centroid of a triangle. When is a point $M$ a centroid of a triangle $ABC$?

Answer (score 0):

The centroid of a triangle with vertices $u, v, w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ has a very simple vector formula: $\frac{u + v + w}{3}$.

So in your diagram,
\begin{align*}
3\vec{MN}
&= 3 (\vec{N} - \vec{M}) \\
&= 3 \left( \frac{\vec{D} + \vec{E} + \vec{F}}{3} - \frac{\vec{A} + \vec{B} + \vec{C}}{3} \right) \\
&= (\vec{D} - \vec{A}) + (\vec{E} - \vec{B}) + (\vec{F} - \vec{C}) \\
&= \vec{AD} + \vec{BE} + \vec{CF},
\end{align*}
proving your result.